# Bazel C++ code coverage with a custom coverage tool (Squish Coco)

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules, bazel-cpp

I couldn't find anything in the official documentation on this. We're using Squish Coco for code coverage and can't use `lcov` for certification reasons, which is the only tool supported by `bazel coverage`.

We're trying to get this running in Bazel. For this we added a toolchain for the Squish Coco Wrappers. Which seems to be the standard way to add different compilers, shown here https://bazel.build/tutorials/ccp-toolchain-config.

However linking fails with `undefined reference to '__cs_tb...'`, because Bazel deletes all the instrumentation files (`*.o.csmes` and `*.csmes`). The same toolchain for clang or gcc works, as presented in the tutorial.

Is there any way to tell Bazel to keep any files with the ending `*.csmes`? I'd like to declare that `cc_library` produces `.o` files and maybe ( not always, depends on instrumentation options) `*.o.csmes`. `cc_binary` amd `cc_test` may create no extension files and `.csmes` files.

Comment: Not sure if this helps: https://kythe.io/ - maybe another approach to extract the need information from the Bazel build

Comment: @Vertexwahn I'm not quite sure what kythe.io does after looking at the webpage. However it seems to extract compilation subcommands. I would like to work from within the Bazel system, since we need the caching of these tests to work.